# Getting error when using substring via android studio

Tags: java, android, string, methods, android-studio

When trying to delete last character, I'm getting an error

```
Cant resolve method substring(int. int)
```

I'm trying to achieve this for `TextView` is that an issue, I'm not sure as I was able to use `.append()` and `.setText()` methods on it successfully.

Is there a chance that some sort of android import is required to use substring method?

```
getUserIn_DEL = (Button) findViewById(R.id.userIn_DEL);
getUserAnswer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userInAnswer);

getUserIn_DEL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!getUserAnswer.getText().equals("?")) {
            String getUserAnswerString = getUserAnswer.getText().toString();
            int userAnswerLength = getUserAnswerString.length();
            int userAnswerLengthMin = userAnswerLength - 1;
            int userAnswerLengthMax = userAnswerLength + 1;
            getUserAnswerString = substring(userAnswerLengthMin, userAnswerLengthMax);
            getUserAnswer.setText(getUserAnswerString);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: there is no such method for textview. hence the error

Comment: pls look at substring @ http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html. use it like getUserAnswerString.substring(param1,param2);

Comment: @Raghunandan Hi I did before posting the question, changed it so substring is applied to a string (see edited answer) yet am still getting that error.

Comment: but you sitll have `getUserAnswerString = substring(userAnswerLengthMin, userAnswerLengthMax);`??. Do you have a custom method substring??

Comment: @Raghunandan yeas, I am so confused to why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an example to illustrate the principle - use the string you have. Let's say your string is:

```
getUserAnswerString = "Nevermind";
```

[image]

Its length is 9. According to [Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), String.substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex):

> Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The substring begins at the specified beginIndex and **extends to the character at index endIndex - 1.**

You want to delete the last character, so in other words, you want to get the characters between indexes 0 and 7 for your new string. To use substring() and get all the characters of the string except for the last one, you need to call substring() with the following parameters:

- first parameter is **0**, which means you start from the first character in your string
- second parameter is **8**; why 8? because the docs say that the **substring extends to the character at index endIndex - 1**, so if 8 is the parameter, your string will extend to the character at index 8-1 which is 7. Of course we don't want to hardcode 8, because if your string changes, this code might break, so let's use the length of the string; it's 9 in this case, so all you need to do is to subtract 1 from the length and pass it as second parameter to substring;

Here's the universal code that will work for any string:

```
    //get length of our string
    int userAnswerLength = getUserAnswerString.length();

    //get all the characters except for the last one ans assign to your variable
    //getUserAnswerString will be "NEVERMIN" after the below line executes
    getUserAnswerString = getUserAnswerString.substring(0, userAnswerLength - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should do it

```
getUserAnswer.getText().substring(userAnswerLengthMin, userAnswerLengthMax);
```